# Java package how to access a class in above folder

Tags: java

Here's how my directory look like:

```
practice(folder)
    GraphTester.java
    graph(folder)
         Digraph.java
         algorithm(folder)
               TopologicalSort.java
```

I want to use `graph.Digraph` and `graph.algorithm.TopologicalSort` from `GraphTester.java`

What I try is this:

```
package graph;

public class Digraph
{
    ...
}
```

```
package graph;
// package graph.algorithm; <-- also doesn't work

public class TopologicalSort
{
    ...
    private Digraph graph; // doesn't work
}
```

My question is, how can I use `Digraph` from inside `TopologicalSort.java`?

==== Update===

I tried the following, but still not working

```
package graph;
//package graph.algorithm; <-- this also didn't work
import graph.Digraph;

public class TopologicalSort
{
    ...
    private Digraph graph;
}
```

I updated how the directory look like above. My intention was to use `GraphTester.java` as an outside class and not make it related to the package `graph` and `graph.algorithm`. But, it seems like putting it under the folder `practice` is causing the problem.

Comment: You need to `import` it.

Comment: You can also refer to it using the fully qualified name, i.e. `graph.Digraph`

Comment: Are you using an IDE? You might want to consider doing that, since they are designed for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `import practice.graph.Digraph;` under your package declaration in `TopologicalSort.java`.

Make sure the package declaration for `TopologicalSort` is `package practice.graph.algorithm;`, it must match the directory structure.

Comment: None of it worked. I tried to put  `package graph.algorithm;
import graph.Digraph;` and `package graph;
import graph.Digraph;` in my `TopologicalSort.java` but still getting `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: @MargoEastham How does your entire directory structure look like and where is your source root? Seems like you have a top level directory which we cannot see in your question? That one should prefix the package and import statements. I.e., what is the name of the folder `GraphTester` resides in?

Comment: Modify your post in order we can see what is the error (line and full mensage) please.

Comment: @KErlandsson I updated my post above. Yes indeed there's another folder containing `GraphTester.java`. So it seems like it will make `GraphTester.java` part of the package; my intention was to make it as a user class that's not related to the package `graph` and `graph.algorithm`

Comment: @MargoEastham I updated my answer to reflect that directory structure (assuming your source root is one level up from `practice`.

Answer (score 2):

*package* statement is used to create a package.

In order to use a package you need to use the *import* starement under the *package* statements follow by the name of the package you want to use.

You can also "import inline" packages, just a way to use clases or interfaces without *import* is to write the full path when you use it.

```
graph.algorithm.TopologicalSort ts = new graph.algorithm.TopologicalSort();
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

add import statements.

import practice.graph.Digraph;

import practice.graph.algorithm.TopologicalSort;